# How to find the Roots of the Polynomial $1 + s^{12}$ analytically

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, control-theory

Is it possible to analytically find the roots of the polynomial $\mathbf{1 + s^{12}}$ where $s$ denotes the Laplace variable? I know that the roots will appear in complex-conjugate pairs lying on the unit circle in the $s$-plane.

Comment: Please suggest some books or papers on solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a formula giving all roots.  Google "roots of complex numbers" to find out how to do this.  Your equation $1+s^{12}=0$ or $s^{12}=-1$ means that you want the $12$th roots if $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $1+s^{12}=0$ iff $s^{12}=-1$ iff $s^{24}=1$ and $s^{12}\ne1$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. But could you please provide the steps?

Comment: @ParijatBhowmick Do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity ? I don't see how it can get any clearer than this, there basically is a formula giving you all solutions for $s$.

Comment: @GEdgar  Excluding $s^{12} = 1$ excludes all 12 extra zeros.

Comment: @Dirk thanks for the reference but in that particular site, the roots of $x^{n} - 1$ are found. In my case, it belongs to the category of $x^{n} + 1$.